# Delete data in database with the insertion function

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I made a TextView that displayed value with multiple line and each line contains 3 fields as shown in the figure below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOZaC.png
I want to display in the database the integers only so the idea that I deployed is that we will delete  the strings "  and app:" at each insertion to keep the numbers only as present in the code below :

```
public void AddContact(Contact c)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(c.getNom());
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.next();
        cv.put("nom ",line);
        if ((line.trim().length()>0)&& (line.trim().equals("<info>")) &&(line.trim().equals("app:"))){
            db.delete("contact",null,null);
            db.insert("contact", null, cv);
        }
    }
```

but it dosen't function .
is there any way to do that?

Comment: The conditions `(line.trim().equals("<info>"))` and `(line.trim().equals("app:"))` can't be true for the same string so the `if` block is never executed. What is their purpose? Also, do you want to remove "<info>" and "app:" from the start of the line and leave only the number?

Comment: yes exactly this what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to remove the first 10 chars from each `line`

```
public void AddContact(Contact c) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(c.getNom());
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.next().trim();
        if (line.startsWith("<info>app:")) {
            line = line.substring(10).trim();
        }
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            cv.put("nom", line);
            db.insert("contact", null, cv);
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is by removing all non-numeric chars:

```
public void AddContact(Contact c) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(c.getNom());
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.next().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            cv.put("nom", line);
            db.insert("contact", null, cv);
        }
    }
}
```